# case sensitive in select2.js dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am currently using **select2.js 4.0.3**

**Scenario**

let's say the dropdown list has these options

- JavaScript
- javascript
- Javascript
- javaScript

so... when user types **java** as of now... the **list shows all the options** (because case doesn't matter as of now)

**Example 1**

What I want to is... when user types **Java** only these options should show up

- JavaScript
- Javascript

**Example 2**

If user types **script** ... these options should show up

- javascript
- Javascript

**Example 3**

for **aS**

- JavaScript
- javaScript

Comment: you can provide your own function to the matcher https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#new-matcher

Comment: can you show the current filtering code.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same issue for a long time, but everywhere I found the opposite questions (how to make select2 case-insensitive), so I was very surprised when I found already working [solution](https://select2.org/searching#customizing-how-results-are-matched) in the documentation.

```js
function matchCustom(params, data) {
    if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
      return data;
    }

    if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
      return null;
    }

    if (data.text.indexOf(params.term) > -1) {
      var modifiedData = $.extend({}, data, true);

      return modifiedData;
    }

    return null;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").select2({
         tags: true,
         matcher: matchCustom
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select>
  <option>javascript</option>
  <option>Javascript</option>
  <option>JavaScript</option>
  <option>javaScript</option>
</select>
```